# Validate user input from prompt in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, validation, input

So I was extending the rock/paper/scissors JS game from Codecademy to validate user input, but I can't get the program to keep on asking for the right user input when the user inserts something other than 'rock', 'paper' or 'scissors'.

```
var userChoice;

userChoice = prompt('Do you choose rock, paper, or scissors?');
console.log('User choice: ' + userChoice);

if (userChoice !== 'rock' && userChoice !== 'paper' && userChoice !== 'scissors') {
    userChoice = prompt('Select again.');
} else if (userChoice === computerChoice) {
    userChoice = prompt('It\'s a tie! Pick again.');
    console.log('New user choice: ' + userChoice);
}

//computer random choice
var computerChoice = Math.random();
console.log('Computer random number: ' + computerChoice);

// assign rock, paper, scissors values
if (computerChoice <= 0.33) {
    computerChoice = 'rock';
} else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = 'paper';
} else {
    computerChoice = 'scissors';
}

console.log('Computer choice: ' + computerChoice);

// compare user and computer choices
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === 'rock') {
        if (choice2 === 'scissors') {
            return 'Rock wins!';
        } else {
            return 'Paper wins!';
        }
    } else if (choice1 === 'scissors') {
        if (choice2 === 'rock') {
            return 'Rock wins!';
        } else {
            return 'Scissors win!';
        }
    } else if (choice1 === 'paper') {
        if (choice2 === 'rock') {
            return 'Paper wins!';
        } else {
            return 'Scissors win!';
        }
    }
};

console.log(compare(userChoice, computerChoice));
```

This works fine the first time the user enters something  like 'r' to the prompt, but if the input is something wrong the second time, it doesn't work and the console logs `undefined` on the last line `console.log(compare(userChoice, computerChoice));` How do I get it to keep on asking for the valid input? Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you run `userChoice = prompt('Select again.');`, you just continue on to complete the rest of the code execution. What you need is some kind of looping condition that checks if they have entered valid input and lets the code continue only once it is valid. 
(hint: "[while](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_while.asp)" loops)

Try out the following:

```
//to do
// after it is a tie, making the same choice doesn't do anything?
// keep on prompting if incorrect input again

// take user input
var userChoice;

userChoice = prompt('Do you choose rock, paper, or scissors?');
console.log('User choice: ' + userChoice);

var valid = false;

//computer random choice
var computerChoice = Math.random();
console.log('Computer random number: ' + computerChoice);

// assign rock, paper, scissors values
if (computerChoice <= 0.33) {
    computerChoice = 'rock';
} else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = 'paper';
} else {
    computerChoice = 'scissors';
}

while (!valid) {
    if (userChoice !== 'rock' && userChoice !== 'paper' && userChoice !== 'scissors') {
        userChoice = prompt('Select again.');
    } else if (userChoice === computerChoice) {
        userChoice = prompt('It\'s a tie! Pick again.');
        //computer random choice
        var computerChoice = Math.random();
        console.log('Computer random number: ' + computerChoice);

        // assign rock, paper, scissors values
        if (computerChoice <= 0.33) {
            computerChoice = 'rock';
        } else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
            computerChoice = 'paper';
        } else {
            computerChoice = 'scissors';
        }
        console.log('New user choice: ' + userChoice);
    } else {
     valid = true;
    }
}


console.log('Computer choice: ' + computerChoice);

// compare user and computer choices
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === 'rock') {
        if (choice2 === 'scissors') {
            return 'Rock wins!';
        } else {
            return 'Paper wins!';
        }
    } else if (choice1 === 'scissors') {
        if (choice2 === 'rock') {
            return 'Rock wins!';
        } else {
            return 'Scissors win!';
        }
    } else if (choice1 === 'paper') {
        if (choice2 === 'rock') {
            return 'Paper wins!';
        } else {
            return 'Scissors win!';
        }
    }
};

console.log(compare(userChoice, computerChoice));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The `while` loop in your code was missing a closing bracket, and the last `else if` comparison had some spelling error. With that fixed, I'm seeing that the check for a tie inside the `while` loop is not working as it should (it doesn't prompt the user again for input). What are we missing?

Comment: It's actually missing the `valid = true;` statement to break out of the `while` loop this time, and from what I can see the check for a tie is still behaving the same way as before :/

Comment: ... that was a test and you passed... I did indeed forget the valid = true statement. Your implementation of the tie condition is working on my end, the prompt keeps being given until the user enters a valid entry that is not a tie, what is your desired output if not this?

Comment: was missing the final `console.log(compare(userChoice, computerChoice));` line. If you have anymore questions let me know

Comment: Heh really? I had caught the function execution missing in the end and added it, but I still don't see the prompt is given when the result is a tie (using your code here). Maybe I am missing something. Thanks a lot so far BTW! ![Console screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ip1fvwdpxvjq7e/Screenshot%202015-07-31%2001.41.38.png?dl=0)

Comment: Ah, I see what your saying, the problem is that the computer's choice should be determined before the user ever inputs their choice. Every time the game results in a tie, both the player and the computer should pick different answers (as it is in actual rock-paper-scissors). Check out my latest edit and note that you can abstract the protocol that determines the computers answer into a separate function since you call it more than once.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues with your code. To solve the first problem you can do this:

```
var userChoice;

userChoice = prompt('Do you choose rock, paper, or scissors?');
console.log('User choice: ' + userChoice);

while (userChoice !== 'rock' && userChoice !== 'paper' && userChoice !== 'scissors') {
    userChoice = prompt('Select again.');
}
```

however, you still have an issue with the second part:

```
if (userChoice === computerChoice) {
    userChoice = prompt('It\'s a tie! Pick again.');
    console.log('New user choice: ' + userChoice);
}
```

This code will never fire because you calculate `computerChoice` AFTER making the comparison. You should move this code into your `compare` function:

```
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        return 'It\'s a tie!';
    } else if (choice1 === 'rock') {
        if (choice2 === 'scissors') {
            return 'Rock wins!';
        } else {
            return 'Paper wins!';
        }
    } else if (choice1 === 'scissors') {
        if (choice2 === 'rock') {
            return 'Rock wins!';
        } else {
            return 'Scissors win!';
        }
    } else if (choice1 === 'paper') {
        if (choice2 === 'rock') {
            return 'Paper wins!';
        } else {
            return 'Scissors win!';
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Appreciate it eddy! Adding the check for a tie inside the `compare` function like that would not prompt the user again for input, it would only log it is a tie to the console. Also, I ran the program a few times and noticed that with only the `while` loop in place, the check for a tie I had in my code actually did run.

Comment: Oh, interesting... well, I'm glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

> it doesn't work and the console logs undefined

Problem is, you are missing the `return` statement in the function `compare()`:

```
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if {
      ...
    }
    return "oops !!"; //<-- missing
};
```

> How do I get it to keep on asking for the valid input?

Using loop can help here. Possibly do..while loop.