# How do I get the return value of a function prompt to apply to more than one if-statement without re-prompting for new value?

Tags: javascript

I am working on rock, paper, scissors basic js game. I am using a basic implementation of a function running another function and keeping score (that I will transfer the logic to my main RPS game logic).

I made a second practice js file to make a super basic implementation for my game function using 'cheese' and 'soup' to set points. I have a while loop in my game() to run play(). it gives playerScore a point if the user says 'cheese', and the computer a point if the user says 'soup'.

However, for my while statement, it tests the prompt for 'cheese' first. if the value is 'soup', instead of using the same prompt and give the computer 1 point, it goes back to the play function to get a new prompt.

for the winner (first one to get to 3 points wins) the computer has to win 6 times because it keeps re-prompting when the user types 'soup'. but the player wins in 3 times.

I am using chrome dev tools, breakpoints, and the console to figure this out on my own. plus some pieces of what answers I can find online.

You can see here the rest of my code so far for my rock, paper, scissors game:
https://github.com/SolomonM23/Odin-Rock-Paper-Scissors

my code below:

```
function play(){
    let user = prompt('say something: ');

    return (user);
}


//loop game() logic

function game(){

    let playerScore = 0;
    let compScore = 0;

    while (playerScore < 4 || compScore < 4){
        if ( play() == 'cheese'){                  //i want the value from this prompt to stay
            ++playerScore;
            console.log('player score: ' + playerScore);
        } else if (play() == 'soup'){                     //the error is a re-prompt here
            ++compScore;
            console.log('compScore: ' + compScore);
        }

        if (playerScore == 3){
            return console.log('Player Wins!');
        } else if (compScore == 3){
            return console.log('Computer Wins!');
        }
    }

    // have not done the loop yet for best of 5 games here
    // let x = 'cheese';

    // for( let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    //     console.log(play());
    // }
}

game();
```

Comment: Save the result as a variable.

Comment: @VLAZ I have the play() function prompt in a variable and the function returns that variable value. is that what you mean? I'm fairly new so my apologies if I'm asking super basic questions.

Comment: `value = play()`

Comment: @VLAZ Thank you! I knew it was something simple I was missing.

Comment: Just to throw in another suggestion: You could also use a [`switch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch). Despite this being its use case, it's probably considered "overkill" or "unnecessarily complex" here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problem

Your problem is relatively simple, the only mistake you are making is that you are prompting the user twice instead of storing the value from the one prompt.

Each time you call the function `play`, JS will prompt for an input. The return value of `play` isn't "saved" between consecutive calls to `play()`. Calling `play()` simply runs the code you have defined for it to run. I.e., it will prompt the user and then return the value *once*. After the function completes execution, the old answer is thrown off the stack (which is why you need to save it) and the computer sets up a new stack or "data context" for the new functional call *with no memory of previous calls*

## Solution

The solution is to simply save the return value of `play()` in a variable! This is an important fundamental lesson in programming. If you want to keep the return value of a function call, you have to store it in a variable.

```
function game(){

    let playerScore = 0;
    let compScore = 0;

    while (playerScore < 4 || compScore < 4){
        const user_response = play(); // store user input in user_response
        if ( user_response == 'cheese'){                  //i want the value from this prompt to stay
            ++playerScore;
            console.log('player score: ' + playerScore);
        } else if (user_response == 'soup'){                     //the error is a re-prompt here
            ++compScore;
            console.log('compScore: ' + compScore);
        }

        if (playerScore == 3){
            return console.log('Player Wins!');
        } else if (compScore == 3){
            return console.log('Computer Wins!');
        }
    }
}
```

You can simplify this even further, since you really don't need the `play()` function as it is defined. If you plan to do some [sanitizing or input checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31737867/validate-user-input-from-prompt-in-javascript), then having a function for getting the user prompt and then re-prompting until they enter a valid entry (i.e. either 'cheese' or 'soup') is a good idea. If not, you can simply do:

```
function game(){

    let playerScore = 0;
    let compScore = 0;

    while (playerScore < 4 || compScore < 4){
        const user_response = prompt("Say something: "); // just directly prompt instead of calling another function
        if ( user_response == 'cheese'){                  //i want the value from this prompt to stay
            ++playerScore;
            console.log('player score: ' + playerScore);
        } else if (user_response == 'soup'){                     //the error is a re-prompt here
            ++compScore;
            console.log('compScore: ' + compScore);
        }

        if (playerScore == 3){
            return console.log('Player Wins!');
        } else if (compScore == 3){
            return console.log('Computer Wins!');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I greatly appreciate your breakdown.